# Linux shell script to change an environment variable

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to write a Linux shell script to change an environment variable 'ROS_IP' to my current IP address.

```
printenv | grep "ROS_IP"
```

returns `ROS_IP=192.168.1.10`

The command

```
ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/'
```

returns my current ip address 192.168.1.2 which is correct

Here is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

#Command to get current IP address and set the output to a variable 'var'
var=$(ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/')
#Make sure var is the correct IP
echo $var
#Set ROS_IP
export ROS_IP=$var
#end script
```

after the script has run, running the command

```
printenv | grep "ROS_IP"
```

still returns the old output `ROS_IP=192.168.1.10`

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

What you want won't work if you *execute* the script via:

```
bash script.sh  # won't work
```

Or:

```
./script.sh  # won't work even if script has executable bit set
```

Instead, you must *source* it:

```
. script.sh
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
source script.sh
```

The issue is that subshells cannot alter the environment of the parent shell.  The `export` command applies to the shell running the script and its subshells but **not** its parent shell. Thus, the commands must be run in the parent shell.  This is what sourcing does.

#### Documentation

Sourcing is documented in `man bash`:

> **.**  filename [arguments]
>   **source** filename [arguments]
>   Read and execute commands from filename **in the current shell environment** and return the exit
>   status of the last command executed from filename.  If filename does
>   not contain a  slash,  filenames  in PATH are used to find the
>   directory containing filename.  The file searched for in PATH need not
>   be executable.  When bash is not in posix mode, the current directory
>   is searched if no file is found in PATH.  If the sourcepath option to
>   the shopt builtin command is turned off, the PATH is not searched.  If
>   any  arguments are  supplied,  they  become the positional parameters
>   when filename is executed.  Otherwise the positional parameters are
>   unchanged.  The return status is the status of the last command exited
>   within the script (0 if no commands are executed), and false if
>   filename is not found or cannot be read. [emphasis added]

Comment: is there a way to put the source script.sh in the actual script? So that way I could still just run the command ./script.sh..... Or would it just be better to make an alias for that?

Comment: If you source scriptA inside scriptB, it is run in scriptB's environment.  So, no, that doesn't help.  As you suggested, though, an alias (or function) would work.